# Why does static electricity on my couch cause my TV screen to turn off?

Tags: electrical, surge-suppression

**Background:**

I have recently moved into a new house. It was built in the 70s and I had some remediation work done on the wiring.

All the outlets were replaced and connected via alumicon connectors. The breakers are all afci, and some combo afci/gfci where needed.

**Behavior:**

I have a Southern Motion motion sofa. It tends to make a lot of static electricity when I get up from it. The sofa has a controller wired to it to control reclining/heating/massage/etc. If I touch that remote control for the couch or any part of the metal frame of the couch and I get a static shock, the TV which is in the same room but on another outlet temporarily blinks out.

That TV was expensive and so this situation makes me a bit uneasy. What's happening and how do I protect the TV?

The TV is on an surge protector.

Comment: you are sending the command true the tv remote, that sofa is not safe

Comment: Is the TV connected to an antenna or cable TV directly, or is it displaying the output of a set-top box or some other video source?

Comment: I imagine the sofa is powered.  Is it on a GFCI protected circuit?

Comment: Does this happen *only* if you are touching the remote? Or only if you are touching the remote or if the remote is sitting on the sofa? Or does it happen even if the remote is elsewhere?

Comment: @Traveler I'm talking about the sofa's remote that controls its heat/massage/reclining/etc. It's wired to the sofa.

Comment: @Sneftel The TV is currently connected to a receiver which is in turn connected to a Nvidia Shield for streaming. I don't have satellite or cable TV service.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact the remote is the one that controls the sofa, it's heating/reclining/massage/etc. It's wired to the sofa directly. Not talking about a TV remote.

Comment: This isn't a home improvement question.

Comment: "the TV which is in the same room but on another outlet [but still the same circuit] temporarily blinks out" .... plug one of them in somewhere else. You have electric motors on the same circuit as your TV. Don't do that. - At least it isn't a blender (on *any* circuit... in *any* house on the entire block) and a CRT....

Comment: @Mazura I don't know where the circuits begin and end precisely. I could run extension  cords for one or the other I suppose. Why is that a concern? The sofa's reclining can't draw too much I'd think.

Comment: *reclining/heating/massage/etc* - I was trying to hint that I'm old and it kinda doesn't matter so much anymore, but you do have motors and a heat coil in there. - If I plug my router into the same circuit as my furnace, I lose internet when the blower kicks on.

Answer (score 2):

My guess: The arc creates a burst of electromagnetic interference, which is absorbed by the HDMI cable from the video source to the receiver, or from the receiver to the TV. This causes it to lose some data and have to resync with the source. In an extreme case, it could need to reestablish the HDCP link, which could take a couple of seconds.

This is not a dangerous situation for the TV. Using shorter and better-shielded HDMI cables might help.

I had a similar issue several years ago, with quite a long HDMI cable and a refrigerator thermostat (with a relay which arced when deenergized). In my case, replacing the compressor relay with a solid-state relay cleared things up. (Obviously this solution isn't applicable to your situation.)

Comment: Built in the 70s, now all gfcis... prob missing the sticker that says no EGC (*equipment grounding connector*; means there's no actual ground wire). Which if it existed might make it not a problem. TV is prob two prong, but the couch might only be getting 2 of the 3 it's looking for. Couch is 'floating' on a lifted ground and has electromechanical things that spin in circles; *there will be EMF*... on top of the *back* EMF the TV already has to deal with from the motors on the same circuit. - Then it gets 20k volts out of nowhere and it *just can't*.

Comment: The wiring is grounded, I had that double-checked before I moved in. The TV and couch are 2 prong, no ground.

Answer (score 0):

A surge protector protects against surges, not electromagnetic noise or grounding issues.

Either you sofa is not wired correctly or it is producing too much noise (electro magnetic).

Suggestions

1. Get two good quality electrical noise suppressors or filters, one each for the TV and the couch.
2. If that doesn't work then get you sofa checked out by an electrician.